# Laravel frequent execute URL

Tags: php, cron, laravel

Is it possible to let laravel run the cron job or automatically execute the URL every 24 hours? Seen queue but it mostly focus on message only.

Comment: I use queue in Laravel for a lots of thing, not only message.

Comment: @crynobone, hi. Do you have any example on how to execute a URL? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use Queues with Laravel](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queues) with a free service like [setcronjob](https://www.setcronjob.com).

Comment: @SLim use push queues + setcronjob to trigger the `Queue:marshall()`. [here](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queues#push-queues). You set the interval etc from setcronjob's interface. Queue service (e.g: iron.io) will marshal and wait until the process is done. **Queueing is not a cronjob itself, but it should be used together with.**

Comment: the setcronjob ain't free :( it can only trigger for about 50 times only.

Comment: @SLim points are like quota (to prevent adding hundreds of cronjobs), For two daily cronjobs, you should be fine with a free account. [check here](https://www.setcronjob.com/prices). **Points = Number of cron executions per day**

Comment: @SLim Enjoy, and happy coding! :)